# jQuery Mobile - Data Attribute options for listview icons

Tags: jquery-mobile

With collapsible sets, there are a few attributes that you can use to define the icon in the collapsible item's various states, for example:

```
data-collapsed-icon="arrow-down"  data-expanded-icon="arrow-up"
```

Does anyone know if there are similar attributes available for the listview widget?  I'd like to set an attribute to use a specific icon when the listview item is set to active.

Comment: What do you mean by active? Once it's clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether such attributes like collapsible's but, you can do like this:

```
$('#yourpage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $("li").tap(function() {
        $(this).buttonMarkup({ icon: "myicon" });
    });  
});
```